# Entity Framework Core Foreign Key Constraint error

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I try to run Update-Database using the Package Manager Console after having run a migration that after looking at it seems fine, no error I can see.
When I run the update, here's what I get:

```
Failed executing DbCommand (19ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [sys].[identity_columns] WHERE [name] IN (N'InviteId', N'Code', N'CreatedBy', N'CreatedDateTime', N'DateCreated', N'DateUsed', N'PhoneNumber', N'Used', N'UserId') AND [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'[Invites]'))
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Invites] ON;
INSERT INTO [Invites] ([InviteId], [Code], [CreatedBy], [CreatedDateTime], [DateCreated], [DateUsed], [PhoneNumber], [Used], [UserId])
VALUES ('random-guid', 45564, NULL, 'random-time', 'random-date', NULL, N'', CAST(0 AS bit), 'the-user-guid'),
('random-guid', 45686, NULL, 'random-time', 'random-date', NULL, N'', CAST(0 AS bit), 'the-user-guid'),
('random-guid', 45645, NULL, 'random-time', 'random-date', NULL, N'', CAST(0 AS bit), 'the-user-guid');
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [sys].[identity_columns] WHERE [name] IN (N'InviteId', N'Code', N'CreatedBy', N'CreatedDateTime', N'DateCreated', N'DateUsed', N'PhoneNumber', N'Used', N'UserId') AND [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'[Invites]'))
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Invites] OFF;
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Invites_AspNetUsers_UserId". The conflict occurred in database "LocalDB", table "dbo.AspNetUsers", column 'Id'.
The statement has been terminated.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean isAsync, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String methodName)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
ClientConnectionId: *something*
Error Number:547,State:0,Class:16
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Invites_AspNetUsers_UserId". The conflict occurred in database "LocalDB", table "dbo.AspNetUsers", column 'Id'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Here are the Tables and their Configuration using the Fluent API:

User:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>
    {
        public ApplicationUser()
        {

        }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public Guid GenderId { get; set; }
        public virtual Gender Gender { get; set; }
        public virtual IReadOnlyCollection<Invite> Invites { get; set; }
    }

public class ApplicationUserConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ApplicationUser> builder)
        {
            builder.Property(p => p.FirstName)
                .IsRequired();

            builder.Property(p => p.LastName)
                .IsRequired();

            builder.Property(p => p.GenderId)
                .IsRequired();

            builder.HasOne<Gender>(d => d.Gender)
                .WithMany(d => d.Users)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.GenderId);

            builder.HasMany<Invite>(d => d.Invites)
                .WithOne(d => d.User)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId);
        }
    }
```

Invites:

```
public class Invite : AuditableEntities
    {
        public Guid InviteId { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public int Code { get; set; }
        public bool Used { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateUsed { get; set; }
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    }

public class InviteConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Invite>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Invite> builder)
        {
            builder.Property(p => p.Code)
                .IsRequired();

            builder.Property(p => p.Used)
                .IsRequired();

            builder.Property(p => p.UserId)
                .IsRequired();

            builder.HasOne<ApplicationUser>(d => d.User)
                .WithMany(d => d.Invites)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId)
                .IsRequired();
        }
    }
```

I honestly don't know what the problem is and it only happens now, what's weird is a couple months ago it worked well so I don't know if it's due to an update in EF Core's system or something.

I know there isn't an `Id` property on the `AppUser` table but `IdentityUser` creates one automatically since I'm inheriting from it.

I’m also adding Seed Data to the migration, I don’t know if that’s the issue but if it is let me know so that I can share it, but there’s nothing I’m seeing that could be wrong there because as you can see in the SQL error statement where it inserts `“the-user-id”` it is a valid Id.

Comment: Try truncate both table and update the databae again.

Comment: Do you mean remove the `Id` field in the `Invite` table as well ?

Comment: No, what I mean is you can try delete all data in the two tables, and update the migration. You can read and search truncate for more information. This will effectively clean the kids table from all data, thus avoiding missing parent when foreign key constraint are added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ForeignKeys cannot have a value that is not also in the primary key column of the referenced table.

Here the error indicates that the foreignKey violation is in `UserId` column of `Invite` table. Also according to the error and in the insert statement, there is an insertion of value `the-user-guid` in the field `UserId`. Since this value is not also in the referenced table, this foreignKey violation error occurred.

So, the error is related to the values being inserted not the definition of the entities. Presume that `User` entity has only one entry or record where `UserId` = 1 When you try to insert new entry for `Invite` entity with `UserId` = 3 as foreignKey and since there are no records for `UserId` = 3 in the referenced entity `User`, the foreignKey violation error occurs. So check that all insertions for `Invite` has values of `UserId` that exists and matches values in referenced table `User`.

Comment: I've updated my post, please let me know what I'm doing wrong. Thank you for helping.

Comment: I am afraid you didn't got the point. Remove the update as it is not helping. The one to many relation between User and Invite is already defined in the fluent API:
builder.HasMany<Invite>(d => d.Invites)
                .WithOne(d => d.User)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId);

Comment: I have updated the answer to clarify further.

Comment: You were right, it was the user Id. The user wasn't created yet so adding the user Id in the Invite seed data wasn't working. I didn't know wrong data could be the cause of foreign key violation. Thank you very much Wael.